# How can I detect multiple items in a list that are separated with a somewhat equivalent list in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I'm coding in python version 3, and I got a `list` with positive "words", but some items hold a space:

```
posWords = ['beautiful', 'love', 'happy day', 'enjoy', 'smelling flowers']
```

However, the text I need to analyse on positive words aren't holding any spaces within items:

```
wordList = ['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling', 'flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy', 'day']
```

I want to iterate over `wordList` and when the algorithm sees words that are also in `posWords`, but merged (e.g. `'happy day'`), remove the corresponding words in `wordList` (`'happy', 'day'`) and add the merged version in `wordList`.

So in the end, the `wordList` must look like this:

```
wordList = ['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy day']
```

BIG UPDATE:

Because I promised you guys to keep you updated, this is my code so far. It was kinda tricky because in my lists with positive words and negative words there where phrases that contained max three words. So I needed to figure out how to work with that. I realised (also because of the answers you guys gave me, thanks again!) that I had to make lists from all the words of the text that needed to be analysed with either 3, 2, or 1 words in one string item so I can check if the items also appear in my lists of positive words end negative words. Here is my code so far. It's kinda bulky, with a lot of copy pasting... Im planning to fix that but im quite tired and weekend is starting now, so no hate please! (tips are welcome tho)

```
    from textblob import TextBlob

# open the files with negative words
negatives = open("neg_dutch_2.txt")

neg_list = []

# push all the words from text file to list
for lines in negatives:
    lines = lines.lower()
    neg_list.append(lines.strip("\n"))

neg_no_space = []
neg_one_space = []
neg_two_spaces = []
neg_three_spaces = []

count = 0

def neg_how_many_spaces(neg_list, neg_no_space, neg_one_space, neg_two_spaces,
                        neg_three_spaces, count):

    # read every word in the list with negative words
    for i in range(len(neg_list)):

        # every word is a phrase, because there are "words" with spaces
        phrase = neg_list[i]

        # look at every character and assign the phrase to a list
        # that correspondes with the number of spaces in it
        for j in range(len(phrase)):
            if phrase[j] == " ":
                count += 1
        if phrase[-1]:
            if count == 1:
                neg_one_space.append(phrase)
            elif count == 2:
                neg_two_spaces.append(phrase)
            elif count == 3:
                neg_three_spaces.append(phrase)
            else:
                neg_no_space.append(phrase)

            # reset the counter to avoid the total sum of spaces in a list
            count = 0

    return neg_list, neg_no_space, neg_one_space, neg_two_spaces,
    neg_three_spaces, count

neg_how_many_spaces(neg_list, neg_no_space, neg_one_space,
                    neg_two_spaces, neg_three_spaces, count)

# open the files with positive words
positives = open("pos_dutch_2.txt")

pos_list = []

# push all the words from text file to list
for lines in positives:
    lines = lines.lower()
    pos_list.append(lines.strip("\n"))

pos_no_space = []
pos_one_space = []
pos_two_spaces = []
pos_three_spaces = []
count = 0

def pos_how_many_spaces(pos_list, pos_no_space, pos_one_space, pos_two_spaces,
                        pos_three_spaces, count):

    # read every word in the list with positive words
    for i in range(len(pos_list)):

        # every word is a phrase, because there are "words" with spaces
        phrase = pos_list[i]

        # look at every character and assign the phrase to a list
        # that correspondes with the number of spaces in it
        for j in range(len(phrase)):
            if phrase[j] == " ":
                count += 1
        if phrase[-1]:
            if count == 1:
                pos_one_space.append(phrase)
            elif count == 2:
                pos_two_spaces.append(phrase)
            elif count == 3:
                pos_three_spaces.append(phrase)
            else:
                pos_no_space.append(phrase)

            # reset the counter to avoid the total sum of spaces in a list
            count = 0

    return pos_list, pos_no_space, pos_one_space, pos_two_spaces,
    pos_three_spaces, count

pos_how_many_spaces(pos_list, pos_no_space, pos_one_space,
                    pos_two_spaces, pos_three_spaces, count)

text = open("nrc_sample.TXT")

# reading the article, using TextBlob library to seperate each word
text = text.read()
blob = TextBlob(text)

# these are words that are bound to the meta-deta of the articlesfile
ruis = ["DOCUMENTS", "SECTION", "LENGTH", "LOAD-DATE", "LANGUAGE",
        "PUBLICATION-TYPE", "JOURNAL-CODE", "BYLINE", "All", "Rights",
        "Reserved", "Copyright", "krant", "Krant", "KRANT", "blz"]

# make a list for all the words in the articles
word_list = []

# and store every word in that list
for word in blob.words:
    if not any(x in word for x in ruis):
       word = word.lower()
       if word.isalpha():
           word_list.append(word)

# variables for the frequencies of negative and positive words in articles
amount_pos = 0
amount_neg = 0
count = 0

phrases_four = []
phrases_three = []
phrases_two = []
phrases_one = []
amount_neg = 0

# PHRASE 4
for i in range(0, len(word_list)-4, 1):
    if word_list[-1]:
        phrase = " "
        strings = word_list[i], word_list[i+1], word_list[i+2], word_list[i+3]
        phrase = phrase.join(strings)
        phrases_four.append(phrase)
        count = 0

for phrase in phrases_four:
    print("phrase4", count, phrase)
    count += 1

    for neg in neg_three_spaces:
        if phrase == neg:
            print("negatief woord^")
            amount_neg += 1

print(amount_neg)

# PHRASE 3
for i in range(0, len(word_list)-3, 1):
    if word_list[-1]:
        phrase = " "
        strings = word_list[i], word_list[i+1], word_list[i+2]
        phrase = phrase.join(strings)
        phrases_three.append(phrase)
        count = 0

for phrase in phrases_three:
    print("phrase3", count, phrase)
    count += 1

    for neg in neg_two_spaces:
        if phrase == neg:
            print("negatief woord^")
            amount_neg += 1

print(amount_neg)

# PHRASE 2
# start at index zero, till one before end of the list
for i in range(0, len(word_list)-2, 1):

    # until it hits the last word of the list, make for every two words in the
    # article next to each other a phrase of two words, so we can check if
    # there are phrases in the article who also exists in the pos or neg wordslists
    if word_list[-1]:
        phrase = " "
        strings = word_list[i], word_list[i+1]
        phrase = phrase.join(strings)
        phrases_two.append(phrase)
        count = 0

# examine each phrase, and check if the same phrase exists in the list
# with negative phrases containing two words
# dont forget to delete the counter, is only for readability
for phrase in phrases_two:
    count += 1

    for neg in neg_one_space:
        if phrase == neg:
            amount_neg += 1

print(amount_neg)

# JUST A WORD
for i in range(0, len(word_list)-1, 1):
    if word_list[-1]:
        phrase = word_list[i]
        phrases_one.append(phrase)
        count = 0

for phrase in phrases_one:
    print("phrase1", count, phrase)
    count += 1

    for neg in neg_no_space:
        if phrase == neg:
            print("negatief woord^")
            amount_neg += 1

print(amount_neg)
```

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: Will `'happy'` and `'day'` (for example) always be consecutive elements in `wordList`, or could they appear anywhere?

Comment: might the phrases be more than 2 words?

Comment: Yes, the words in wordList will always be in consecutive order. This is part of the problem, because if the appear elsewhere in the list, they wouldn't be counted as one positive word, for `happy day`  is one positive "word" @thesilkworm. And yes, the phrases could be more than 2 words @Chris_Rands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
posWords = ['beautiful', 'love', 'happy day', 'enjoy','smelling flowers']
wordList = ['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling', 'flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy', 'day'] 

# Create a sentence for the wordList.
joinedWordList = " ".join(wordList)

# Find all phrases in the posWords list.
phrases = [elem for elem in posWords if len(elem.split()) > 1]

# For every phrase, locate it in the sentence, 
# count the space characters which is the same number as the index of the first word of phrase in the word list,
# insert the phrase and delete the word that combine the phrase from the wordList.
for phrase in phrases:
    try:
        i = joinedWordList.index(phrase)
        spaces = len([letter for letter in joinedWordList[:i] if letter==' '])
        wordList.insert(spaces,phrase)
        del wordList[spaces+1:spaces+1 + len(phrase.split())]
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(wordList)
```

Output:

```
['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy day']
```

Comment: Thank you, if i try it with a longer sentence the program is buggy and does not erase the words in the right way. But this helps me a lot and the following days I wil try to solve this on my own. I keep you updated

Comment: By the way, this was yet the best solution, as the other answers didn't correctly processed positive words for more than two words

Comment: @mick_zon_24 thanks for the feedback, would you mind showing the specific case in which the above solution gets buggy? Please do, so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that would work for any phrase length:

```
posWords = ['beautiful', 'love', 'happy day', 'enjoy','smelling flowers']
wordList = ['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling', 'flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy', 'day'] 

for w in posWords:
    nrWords = len(w.split(' '))
    if nrWords > 1:
        word_array = w.split(' ')
        word_index_array = [wordList.index(w) for w in word_array]
        index_difference_array = [abs(b-a) for a in word_index_array[0:-1] for b in word_index_array[1:]]

        if sum(index_difference_array) == len(index_difference_array): #elements are consecutive in wordList
            for elem in word_array:
                wordList.remove(elem)                        
            wordList.insert(word_index_array[0], w)
```

Output will be:

```
['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy day']
```

But if we for example input something like:

```
posWords = ['beautiful', 'love', 'happy day', 'enjoy','smelling flowers on']
wordList = ['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling', 'flowers', 'on', 'a', 'happy', 'day']
```

The output will be:

```
['I', 'enjoy', 'smelling flowers on', 'a', 'happy day']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
>>> m=["good bad", "enjoy", "play"]
>>> l=["good", "bad", "happy", "delight"]
>>>
>>> for e in m:
...     tmp = e.split(" ")
...     if(len(tmp) > 1):
...             l = [ent for ent in l if ent not in tmp]
...             l.append(" ".join(tmp))
...
>>>
>>> l
['happy', 'delight', 'good bad']
```